# res in controller function fails due to being undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, sails.js

I'm new to Sails (and a jr. dev to boot) and have been working through the `Sailsjs in Action` book. Given some previous experience with TypeScript I wanted to experiment with the framework in that capacity. However I've hit a road block when trying to return response statuses and information via my API.

Every time I try to use the `res` in my controller I receive a:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined`. Based on the book and the documentation, I'm under the impression that would get set automatically per this example from the docs:

```
await User.create({name:'Finn'});

return res.ok();
```

and this example from the book:

```
signup: function(req, res) {
    var options = {**grab request data**};
    User.create(options).exec(function(err, createdUser){
    if(err){
      return res.negotiate(err);
    }
    return res.json(createdUser);
}
```

So I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious but I'm not sure what. The project compiles just fine and I've got the [documented typescript libraries](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-type-script) installed/configured. Even matching that function there returns the same TypeError to me.

Another set of eyes would be greatly appreciated. Controller code below.

```
declare const sails: any;

import { boatInterface } from '../../interfaces/boat';

module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'new-boat',
    description: 'create a new boat model',

    inputs: {
      modelName:{
        required: true,
        type: 'string',
      },
      yearBuilt:{
          required: true,
          type: 'number'
      }
    },


    exits: {

      success: {
        description: 'New boat model was created successfully.'
      },

      invalid: {
        responseType: 'badRequest',
        description: 'The provided boat info was invalid.'
      },

      modelAlreadyCreated: {
        statusCode: 409,
        description: 'The provided boat model has already been 
        created.',
      },

    },

    fn: async function (req: any, res: any){  
        console.log('building boat');

        let boatRequest: boatInterface = {
            modelName: req.modelName.toLowerCase(),
            yearBuilt: req.yearBuilt
        }

        //confirming data has been formatted correctly
        console.log(boatRequest);

        let newBoat = await sails.models.boat.create(boatRequest)
        .intercept('E_UNIQUE', 'modelAlreadyCreated')
        .fetch();

        //confirming new boat exists
        console.log(newBoat);
        console.log("request successful");

        //res remains undefined and throws an error on attempted return
        console.log(res);
        return res.ok();

      }


};
```

Here's the error with some console logs included. Thanks in advance!

```
building boat
{ modelName: 'kraken', yearBuilt: 1337 } <-- Request formats correctly
{ createdAt: 1566173040652,
  updatedAt: 1566173040652,
  id: 6,
  modelName: 'kraken',
  yearBuilt: 1337 } <-- new db entry is returned via fetch()
request successful
undefined <-- attempt to log the res returns undefined
(node:3738) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pitterpatter/Repos/learn/sails-learn/freeform/api/controllers/boat/new-boat.ts:67:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [actions2](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?what-does-an-action-file-look-like).

Your handler function will be given 2 parameters - `inputs` and `exits` as you've defined in the objects above it.

```
fn: async function (inputs: any, exits: any) {
```

`inputs` will be an object that contains parmeters given by a user that you've defined in the `inputs` part of your action (form data/query parameters/route parameters).
In this case it'd contain a `modelName` and `yearBuilt`, something like
`{ modelName: 'lemon', yearBuilt: 2012.3 }`

`exits` will contain a few default methods - `exits.success()` and `exits.error()`, as well as the `invalid` and `modelAlreadyCreated` which you've defined.

TLDR try this

```js
fn: async function (inputs: any, exits: any) {  
    let boatRequest: boatInterface = {
        modelName: inputs.modelName.toLowerCase(),
        yearBuilt: inputs.yearBuilt
    }

    let newBoat = await sails.models.boat.create(boatRequest)
        .intercept('E_UNIQUE', 'modelAlreadyCreated')
        .fetch();

    return exits.success(newBoat);
}
```

You ***can*** access the "raw [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) response object" deely that you're looking for by using `this.res.ok(...)` or `this.req.something`, but it's recommended you use the appropriate "exit" instead.